# "Array subscript is not an integer" error when indexing array using an enum class value

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to implement a debug logger that would look like this:

```
loggingEvent("setting Input, task=%u, input=%u, select=%s", task, input, 
NAME[select]);
```

Where

```
const char* NAME[] = 
{
    "A",
    "B",
    "C",
    "D"
};
```

So far I have done this:

```
void loggingEvent( const char* fmt, ... );
```

and

```
void loggingEvent( const char* fmt, ... )
{
    char buffer[256];  //Hope this is OK :)
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vsnprintf(buffer,256,fmt, args);
    perror(buffer);
    va_end(args);
}
```

But I get the error:

```
error: array subscript is not an integer
warning: zero-length gnu_printf format string
```

I just cannot think how I can do this.  I do not know how many inputs I will get, it can be like this

```
loggingEvent("setting Input, input=%u, select=%s", input, 
NAME[select]);
```

Or Like this

```
loggingEvent("setting Input, input=%u, select=%s, select2=%s", input, 
NAME[select], NAMETWO[select2]);
```

How should I go about this?  I need to use that name and my own logging function.

`select` and `select2` are enum classes like this

```
enum class HW
{
    HW00, 
    HW01, 
    HW02
}
```

Comment: Get log4cpp, save yourself some time.

Comment: What's the type of *select* and *select2*? Check it before doing something...

Comment: How did you declare or define `select`?

Comment: They are enum classes, ad edited into my post above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`enum class` cannot be implicitly used as an integer, neither an array subscription. You need either to explicitly cast it to an integral type:

```
NAME[static_cast<std::size_t>(select)]
```

or change the way your NAME is defined, e.g. by using a `std::map<HW, std::string>` type,

or change `enum class` into a plain old `enum`

Comment: Yes you're right enum works but enum class does not.  Thanks alot!